# 10 gig ethernet in Java?

Tags: java, networking, ethernet

Does Java 6 support 10 gig ethernet out of the box?

It seems like it shouldn't require Java changes, but I thought I remembered that Java 7 was adding 10 gig support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java doesn't care about the underlying network infrastructure when it uses sockets, etc. If 100Gbit Ethernet was invented tomorrow, Java would support it.

So, basically, the answer is **yes**.

I'm not sure where you found the 10Gbit; it might be some other Java-based product.

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing you saw some article (like http://www.devwebsphere.com/devwebsphere/2006/07/10gb_ethernet_p.html) questioning whether the IO libraries in pre Java 7 were capable of filling a 10gb pipe, that made reference to the features in the new NIO2 libraries in Java 7 ([JSR 203](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=203)).

Comment: +1. It seems likely JSR 203 is what the OP was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

10 GB Ethernet should be presented by the OS in the same way as 1 GB Ethernet is.

What you may be confusing this with is support for Infiniband over Socket Direct Protocol (SDP) on Solaris. See [JDK7 features](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/).